# New persimmon tree bought from home depot dying

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, persimmon

I bought the young persimmon tree from Home Depot last week. but it seems like it is not doing so well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

We mixed the soil provided in the base with the original soil in the ground, and put ~3 inch of mulch as instructed. But it looks like the leafs are almost falling apart.

What would be causing this? is it because we did not gave enough water? or because we gave too much fertilizer? Our area is a bit windy but the temperature isn't that low (~60F, or 17C)

Comment: When you brought it home from the store, was it inside the body of the vehicle, or in the back of a pickup truck, exposed to wind on the highway?

Comment: Inside the vehicle. It only took like 10 minutes to bring though

Comment: Where was the tree when you bought it at Home Depot, outside completely in the open, outside but under cover, or inside? How dry or wet has your weather been since you planted it?

Comment: outside completely open (it looked okay when we bought)

Comment: The soil was moisty since we planted but I think we might not gave enough water though